# Rust Trying load jsonFile

Tags: json, rust

I'm having trouble trying to get Rust to load jsonFile. Compilation goes through, but an error occurs during execution and is killed.Also, no error code found.

Source code is

```rust
use iced::{
    executor, Align, Application, Clipboard, Column, Command, Element,
    Length, Row, Settings, Text,
};

use serde::{Serialize, Deserialize};
use std::collections::HashMap;
use std::fs::File;
use std::io::BufReader;

#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize, Debug)]
#[serde(rename_all = "PascalCase")]
struct Tasks {
    task: Task
}

#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize, Debug)]
#[serde(rename_all = "PascalCase")]
struct Task {
    deadline: String,
    details: String,
    user: HashMap<String, String>
}


struct GUI;

impl Application for GUI {
    type Executor = executor::Default;
    type Message = ();
    type Flags = ();

    fn new(_flags: ()) -> (GUI, Command<Self::Message>) {
        (GUI, Command::none())
    }

    /// Sets the window title.
    fn title(&self) -> String {
        String::from("rust_gui_test")
    }

    fn update(
        &mut self,
        _message: Self::Message,
        _clipboard: &mut Clipboard,
    ) -> Command<Self::Message> {
        Command::none()
    }

    fn view(&mut self) -> Element<Self::Message> {
        
        let file = File::open("task.json").unwrap();
        let reader = BufReader::new(file);
        let deserialized: Tasks = serde_json::from_reader(reader).unwrap();
        let serialized = deserialized.task.deadline;
        let json_data = serde_json::to_string(&serialized).unwrap(); //&alloc::String::String
        let textarea = Text::new(json_data).size(60);


        // prepare column
        Column::new()
        .push(textarea)
        .push(
            Row::new()
                .spacing(10),
        )
        .spacing(10)
        .padding(10)
        .width(Length::Fill)
        .height(Length::Fill)
        .align_items(Align::Center)
        .into()
    }
   
}

fn main() -> iced::Result {
    GUI::run(Settings::default())
}
```

test json is

```
{
    "task1": {
      "deadline": "2000-01-01 00:00:00",
      "details": "Folder/Path",
      "target":{
        "alice": {
          "progress": 0,
          "comment":"no"
        },
        "Bob": {
          "progress": 1,
          "comment":"ok"
        }
      }
    },
    "task2": {
      "deadline": "2222-01-01 00:00:00",
      "details": "Folder/Path",
      "target":{
        "alice": {
          "progress": 0,
          "comment":"no"
        },
        "Carol": {
          "progress": 1,
          "comment":"ok"
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Err is

```
Running `target\debug\progress_app.exe`
thread 'main' panicked at 'called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err` value: Error("missing field `Task`", line: 30, column: 3)', src\main.rs:57:67
note: run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace
error: process didn't exit successfully: `target\debug\progress_app.exe` (exit code: 0xc0000005, STATUS_ACCESS_VIOLATION)
```

How can I get all of json's targets while avoiding errors?
Changing RUST_BACKTRACE to 1 would only produce something like a record, and the error would not change.

Comment: You probably want to decode to a `HashMap<String, Task>`

Comment: Your test json's format doesn't match the code struct: `task1` and `task2` can't be matched with the task key in code. If the JSON is generated by your code, I suggest modify it to add a `id` filed, then the `task1` and `task2` can be unified with key `task`